# Recursion in C, segfault confusion

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, segmentation-fault

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_LEN   45

int howmany (int table[] , int number , int frequency , int index) {

    if (index <= ARRAY_LEN) {

        if (table[index] == number) {
            frequency++;
        }
        howmany(table , number , frequency , index++);

    }
    return frequency;
}

int main(void) {
    int array[] = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,6,5,6,7,8,9,9,8,7,8,9,9};
    int frequency = 0;
    int chosen;

    printf("Select chosen number\n");
    scanf("%d" , &chosen);

    frequency = howmany(array ,chosen ,frequency , 0);

    printf("Frequency of %d is %d times.\n" , chosen , frequency);

    return 0;
}
```

So I have an exam tomorrow and I had a problem with this simple program that counts how many times a number is found in a table with recursion. Please help me find the problem because Debugger finds a problem in the line where I call the function howmany, however I cant seem to detect what it is. Thanks

Comment: What problem do you have with this program? What do you expect it to do? What does it actually do?

Comment: Consider what the value of `index++` is. It is the original value of `index` before incrementing it, which means that you see the same value of `index` in all your calls. The segfault means that the program runs out of stack space. Here, you don't really need an increment of `index` in your function. Say what you mean: `index + 1`.

Comment: When `howmany` calls `howmany` recursively, why does it throw the return value away? What purpose does that serve? And why do you pass `frequency` to `howmany`? Why not *just* have it return the frequency? With no comments, it's hard to make any sense out of this code.

Comment: well ill try to explain. The table has 45 numbers and the howmany function tries to find how many times the variable number exists inside the table. The index variable is used to run as a counter in the table and thats why I increment it. So I check every position of the table till the 44 pos.

Comment: ΥΕΑΗ M.Oehm you are right, thank you :) I didn't notice that it is postfix, thanks! Also about the returning of frequency I actually return it I just uploaded a previous version of the program before I fixed it. Thanks David Schwartz.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is too complicated and wrong.

For starters the valid range of indices for an array that has for example `45` elements is `0-44`

Or in this call

```
howmany(table , number , frequency , index++);
                                     ^^^^^^^
```

the current value of the variable `index` is passed to the function instead of the increased value as for example

```
howmany(table , number , frequency , ++index);
                                     ^^^^^^^^
```

And moreover the variable `frequency` does not accumulate the number of the occurrences in the array of the value of the variable `number`.

The function can be written simpler just in one line.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t how_many ( const int a[] , size_t n, int value ) 
{
    return n == 0 ? 0 : ( a[0] == value ) + how_many( a + 1, n - 1, value );
}

int main( void ) 
{
    int a[] = 
    {
        9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
        8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,
        9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 8, 7, 8, 9, 9
    };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );

    int chosen;

    printf( "Select chosen number: ");
    scanf( "%d" , &chosen );

    size_t frequency = how_many( a, N, chosen );

    printf( "Frequency of %d is %zu times.\n" , chosen , frequency );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Select chosen number: 7
Frequency of 7 is 7 times
```

.

Comment: Just  said I made some fixes after i uploaded the program but thank you for your solution.

Comment: Ι guess so @VladfromMoscow ^^